# GPX import to Filemaker Pro using XSL stylesheet

Tags: xslt, filemaker, gpx

I know about GPSbabel and have used it for transforming GPX files into CSV that I can then import into Filemaker Pro for manipulation. However, I'd like to be able to import GPX files more simply & neatly into FMP and hoped I could write a XSL stylesheet to convert the GPX form of XML to the FMPXMLRESULT grammar.

I'm looking at GPX files from Garmin Foretrex, Dakota, Nuvi & GPSmap296 devices. My latest attempt at a XSL stylesheet (using snippets cribbed from various examples) looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="trkseg">
        <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
            <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
            <PRODUCT BUILD="01-25-2011" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 11.0v3"/>
            <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="Yyyy-m-d" LAYOUT="" NAME="gpx_import_test.fp7" RECORDS="{@count}"
                TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss "/>
            <METADATA>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ele" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="lat" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="lon" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="time_text" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            </METADATA>
            <RESULTSET FOUND="@count">
                <xsl:for-each select="trkpt">
                    <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="{position()}">
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="lat"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="lon"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ele"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="time_text"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </RESULTSET>
        </FMPXMLRESULT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to use the above stylesheet, FMP complains "XML parsing error:  invalid document structure".

I'd welcome any suggestions - I guess I'm making some very simple and obvious error.

regards

Rowland

Here is a snipped version of a typical GPX file from a Garmin Dakota 20 that I am trying to import.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3"
xmlns:wptx1="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1"
xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1"
creator="Dakota 20" version="1.1"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1
http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd
http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3
http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd
http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1
http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtensionv1.xsd
http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1
http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd">
<metadata>
<link href="http://www.garmin.com">
<text>Garmin International</text>
</link>
<time>2011-10-21T16:55:50Z</time>
</metadata>
<trk>
<name>Current Track: 20 OCT 2011 10:31</name>
<extensions>
<gpxx:TrackExtension>
<gpxx:DisplayColor>Black</gpxx:DisplayColor>
</gpxx:TrackExtension>
</extensions>
<trkseg>
<trkpt lat="51.6084605176" lon="-2.2182025295">
<ele>43.40</ele>
<time>2011-10-20T09:31:44Z</time>
</trkpt>
<trkpt lat="51.6084605176" lon="-2.2182025295">
<ele>47.24</ele>
<time>2011-10-20T09:31:53Z</time>

</trkpt>
</trkseg>
</trk>
</gpx>
```

Answer (score 1):

Several problems here. One is this:

```
<xsl:template match="trkseg">
```

You do not start at the root, so the XSLT processor will process the root and all other elements using default rules (which are to output the value of the element). This may add extra text around `FMPXMLRESULT`. To fix it we need to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//trkseg/trkpt"> <!-- or use a full path -->
    ...
  </xsl:for-each>
```

This is not enough because `trkseg` is not just `trkseg`, it's `trkseg` in the GPX namespace. Without proper namespace declaration the stylesheet won't find the elements at all. And the final problem is that `lat` and `lon` are attributes and you need to refer to them as `@lat` and `@lon`. Here's the working XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:gpx="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="gpx">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
            <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
            <PRODUCT BUILD="01-25-2011" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 11.0v3"/>
            <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="Yyyy-m-d" 
                LAYOUT=""  NAME="gpx_import_test.fp7" RECORDS="{@count}"
                TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss "/>
            <METADATA>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="ele" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="lat" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="lon" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="time" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            </METADATA>
            <RESULTSET FOUND="count(//gpx:trkseg/gpx:trkpt)">
                <xsl:for-each select="//gpx:trkseg/gpx:trkpt">
                    <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="{position()}">
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@lat"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@lon"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="gpx:ele"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="gpx:time"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </RESULTSET>
        </FMPXMLRESULT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Mikhail - thanks for that, I've obviously not grasped some fundamentals here! Making that change got me to the dialogue box for choosing which fields to import, but when I went ahead with that, no records were imported to the FMP file. (I've done some exprts & imports with the FMPRESULT grammar so I know that part is working.) I guess I've still got something silly with the loop part.

Comment: Mikhail - thanks, I've made those changes but still get the same effect, FMP goes ahead & appears to do a import, but comes back with no records imported (& no errors either). Here is a snipped version of one of the GPX files I'm trying to import:

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise I couldn't add the GPX code snippet in a comment so have edited my original post to show it there.

Comment: @user1034481: done, here's a working XSLT. I've tested it with FM 10, and think it will work with v11 too.

Comment: Mikhail - yes, that works OK for me now. Thanks so much for taking all that time to answer my question. I should now be much better-equipped to poke around a bit more on my own. Again, I really appreciate your help. in friendship, Rowland

Answer (score 0):

> Here is a xslt file to read out only the waypoints, not the tracks: By
>   the way: I added the fields time, name, sym and type to the import. If
>   not needed, delete the corresponding lines in this file.
>
> Copy and store the text below the dotted line in a file named
>   "yourchoice.xslt" where "yourchoice" might be any name you want and
>   use this as a xslt transformation file in filemaker.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:gpx="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
    exclude-result-prefixes="gpx">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
            <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
            <PRODUCT BUILD="01-25-2011" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 11.0v3"/>
            <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="Yyyy-m-d" 
                LAYOUT=""  NAME="gpx_import_test.fp7" RECORDS="{@count}"
                TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss "/>
            <METADATA>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="latitude" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="longitude" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="elevation" TYPE="NUMBER"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="time" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="name" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="sym" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="type" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            </METADATA>
            <RESULTSET FOUND="count(gpx:wpt)">
                <xsl:for-each select="gpx:wpt">
                    <ROW MODID="0" RECORDID="{position()}">
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@lat"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@lon"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="gpx:ele"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="gpx:time"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                          <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="gpx:name"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                          <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="gpx:sym"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                          <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="gpx:type"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                    </ROW>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </RESULTSET>
        </FMPXMLRESULT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```